# create react app eslint prettier configuration

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint, prettier, linter

I'm getting these error messages:
[image: error]

but i don't get any errors on vscode

this is my elint configration

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'prettier',
    'prettier/react',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['react', 'import', 'prettier'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'import/named': 'off',
    'import/no-self-import': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'no-param-reassign': [
      'error',
      { props: true, ignorePropertyModificationsFor: ['draft'] },
    ],
  },
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [['@', path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, './src'))]],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      },
      node: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

whats wrong with my configuration?

this is my component that i getting error:
[image: component]

as you see there is no error.

**note:** eslint and prettier extensions are enabled and work successfully. and before these errors , i got errors and vscode displays errors and i'm sure vscode eslint works.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the errors are caused by the [webpack configuration](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js) which ships with create-react-app.
The webpack process started behind the scenes when calling `npm start` in your project doesn't know anything about the aliases you specified in your custom eslint configuration file. Your custom eslint-config-file is only used by your editor (or more specific by your enabled eslint-extension) and I believe there is no smooth way to change this (without creating your own webpack config).

See also https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#displaying-lint-output-in-the-editor which describes what I have written above.

> Note that even if you customise your ESLint config, these changes will only affect the editor integration. They won’t affect the terminal and in-browser lint output. This is because Create React App intentionally provides a minimal set of rules that find common mistakes.